# Displaying multiple charts on the same view

Tags: laravel, charts, laravel-5.4

I want to display all my charts on the same view I used lavacharts I gave different no to my charts but in the view it shows me that the last chart in the controller.

Controller code:

```
function l()

{

    $lava = new Lavacharts; // See note below for Laravel



    $reasons = \Lava::DataTable();

    $abs=Absencecollab::all();

    $r=$abs->count();

    $absm=Absencecollab::where('motif','maladie');

    $tm=$absm->count();

    $absc=Absencecollab::where('motif','conge');

    $tc=$absc->count();

    $absnj=Absencecollab::whereNull('motif');

    $tnj=$absnj->count();

    $pm=($tm100)/$r;

    $pc=($tc100)/$r;

    $pnj=($tnj100)/$r;



    $reasons->addStringColumn('Reasons')

            ->addNumberColumn('Percent')

            ->addRow(['Maladie',$pm ])

            ->addRow(['Conge',$pc])

            ->addRow(['Absence non justifiée',$pnj]);



    \Lava::PieChart('IMDB', $reasons, [

        'title'  => 'Abscences collaborateurs par motif',

        'is3D'   => true,

        'slices' => [

            ['offset' => 0.2],

            ['offset' => 0.25],

            ['offset' => 0.3]

        ]

    ]);







    $reasons1 = \Lava::DataTable();

    $abs1=Absence::all();

    $r1=$abs1->count();

    $absm1=Absence::where('motif','maladie');

    $tm1=$absm1->count();

    $absc1=Absence::where('motif','conge');

    $tc1=$absc1->count();

    $absnj1=Absencecollab::whereNull('motif');

    $tnj1=$absnj1->count();

    $pm1=($tm1100)/$r;

    $pc1=($tc1100)/$r;

    $pnj1=($tnj1*100)/$r;



    $reasons1->addStringColumn('Reasons')

            ->addNumberColumn('Percent')

            ->addRow(['Maladie',$pm1 ])

            ->addRow(['Congé parents',$pc1])

            ->addRow(['Absence non justifiée',$pnj1]);



    \Lava::PieChart('abse', $reasons1, [

        'title'  => 'Abscences enfants par motif',

        'is3D'   => true,

        'slices' => [

            ['offset' => 0.2],

            ['offset' => 0.25],

            ['offset' => 0.3]

        ]

]);

return view('statistiquesg');
```

view code

```
@piechart('IMDB', 'chart-div')

          <canvas id="line" height="300" width="450"></canvas>

      </div>

  </section>

</div>

<!-- Bar -->



<div class="col-lg-6">

  <section class="panel">

      <header class="panel-heading">

         Absence enfants

      </header>

      <div class="panel-body text-center" id="chart-div">

      @piechart('abse', 'chart-div')



          <canvas id="bar" height="300" width="500"></canvas>

      </div>

  </section>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter of `@piechart` is the ID of the div, both pie charts are using the `chart-div` id.

Comment: but i use the  id of chart in the first parameter